# VBA - ComboBox.value returns zero when called in modules

Tags: vba, combobox, userform, solidworks

I am trying to make a Solidworks Macro by using VBA.

The idea was to import DXF file from certain folder.

First stage : scan all existing DXFfile using Dir method (done)

Second stage : add filename to combobox using .AddItem FileName (done)

Third stage : getting the value of selected combobox from module (problem)

below is my rough code

```html
'Within UserForm

Public folderpath, filepath, FileName as String
Public fullpath as String

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

folderpath = "insert path"
filepath = folderpath & "*.dxf"
FileName = Dir(filepath)

Do Until FileName = ""
   
    With ComboBox1
        .AddItem FileName
    End With
    
    FileName = Dir
Loop

'The FileName was added to ComboBox1 successfully

End Sub


Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()

fullpath = folderpath & ComboBox1.Value

'It returns the fullpath no problem
Debug.Print fullpath

End Sub
```

Here comes the problem

```html
'Import Module
Sub import()

Dim UserForm1 as New Form

'Here I tried to test if the fullpath is successfully called within the module, but it returns nothing
Debug.Print Form.fullpath

'Ignore the SW codes
Set swApp = _
Application.SldWorks

Set Part = swApp.ActiveDoc
boolstatus = Part.Extension.SelectByID2("FRONT", "PLANE", 0, 0, 0, False, 0, Nothing, 0)
Dim myFeature As Object
Set myFeature = Part.FeatureManager.InsertDwgOrDxfFile(Form.fullpath)


End Sub
```

I have declared that all path was set to Public, which should be readable by all modules. It works perfectly with TextBox but not with ListBox or ComboBox. Any idea?

Comment: Is `Debug.Print Form.pathtest` a typo?  `pathtest` does not exist in `Userform`.  Did you mean `Debug.Print Form.fullpath`?

Comment: sorry Chris, it is a typo, thanks for noticing.

Answer (score 0):

I just found out that calling the same UserForm within 2 different modules returns Null in the later modules, I fixed this and it successfully called the ComboBox.Value.

Sorry for the junk post. I guess I figured it out myself afterall.